# Manipulating Embedded Kaltura Player from Javascript

Tags: javascript, kaltura

I have a web application and I have embedded a video player. It turns out that the video player is Kaltura. I was able to successfully make it autoplay due to the flashvars property. However, I want it to auto-fullscreen when it starts to play.

With this requirement, I searched and found that Kaltura has a Javascript API. I also found certain codes that will help me in this requirement.

```
kWidget.addReadyCallback(function( playerId ){
    var kdp = document.getElementById(playerId); 
    kdp.kBind("doPlay", function(){
        kdp.sendNotification('openFullScreen'); 
    }); 
    kdp.kBind("doPause", function(){
        kdp.sendNotification('closeFullScreen');
    });
    kdp.kBind("openFullScreen", function(){
        $("#fslog").append("openFullScreen\n");
    });
    kdp.kBind("closeFullScreen", function(){
        $("#fslog").append("closeFullScreen\n");
    });
});
```

When I read the documentation regarding the API, it has a kWidget which is apparently part of the API. However, I cannot find this API or the js file for this.

Furthermore, I am not using just the player, I just have an embedded Kaltura player from an internal company site.

The src is: `https://internalsite.company.com/embed/secure/iframe/entryId/videoid/uiConfId/integers?(string of flashvars)`

Now, I cannot understand how am I suppose to integrate this if I can't find the relevant js files for the Kaltura player. If someone can help me just to start out on integrating Kaltura (like a simple code or a link to the tutorial) it would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If you must embed via an `iframe` with `src` set to `https://internalsite.company.com/embed/secure/iframe/...`, then you probably won't be able to access player's JS API. This is a MediaSpace endpoint for internal embeds (protected via SSO).

You can try requesting a different player uiConfId ID from the company that provided you with this endpoint, that will have the full screen support build in.